# How to share a same object across modules in Python

Tags: python, oop, logging

I'm creating a simple logging module (I'm aware of `logging`, let me reinvent the wheel, one simpler, suited to my needs and on top of everything that allows me to learn in the way I make it).

I'm trying to mimic the API of `logging`, thus the core of the logging system is a `Logger` instance that contains a list of `handlers`, which eventually deliver the info either through the console (via a `StreamHandler` object) or to text files (via a `FileHandler` object). These classes are all defined in a module, which I import to the main program and the libraries I want to use logging on.

The problem is that I'd like to define the logger **just once**, in the main program, and use it across the modules I import. I do not want to define different loggers not only because I'd like to set the logging setup once, but also because this object includes the handling of files, and I'd like to make this centralised, not with various objects adding lines to the same file from different places.

What's the most pythonic way to define this pattern?

Comment: Create a function which initializes a looger instance, and then save it, e.g. to a container in your module namespace. Then in each file that you use the instance, use a `get_logger()` function which simply retrieves that instance

Comment: Sounds good, but got lost. Could you develop the “save it in a container in your module namespace”?

Comment: Does what you propose go in the line of this? https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/a-globals-class-pattern-for-python/ If so, I still don’t know how to retrieve from other module’s namespace. If you propose an example of how to do this as answer, this would be the answer I’m starting to envisage.

Comment: For example, would it be sensible to implement this retrieve function by calling ‘globals()’?

Answer (score 0):

you can define the logger in a class and use singleton pattern to be sure that the class will be instantiated only owns :

```
class SingletonMeta(type):
    """
    The Singleton class can be implemented in different ways in Python. Some
    possible methods include: base class, decorator, metaclass. We will use the
    metaclass because it is best suited for this purpose.
    """

    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Possible changes to the value of the `__init__` argument do not affect
        the returned instance.
        """
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            cls._instances[cls] = instance
        return cls._instances[cls]


class Singleton(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
    def some_business_logic(self):
        """
        Finally, any singleton should define some business logic, which can be
        executed on its instance.
        """

        # ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # The client code.

    s1 = Singleton()
    s2 = Singleton()

    if id(s1) == id(s2):
        print("Singleton works, both variables contain the same instance.")
    else:
        print("Singleton failed, variables contain different instances.")
```

or you can define your logger as a class and use a decorator (cache method) :

```
def memoize(function):
  memo = {}
  def wrapper(*args):
    if args in memo:
      return memo[args]
    else:
      rv = function(*args)
      memo[args] = rv
      return rv
  return wrapper


class log:
    def __init__(self):
       ....
    def methdo(self):
       return logger

@memorize
def create_logger():

  return log.method()
```

Comment: This ensures that there will be just one logger. But how do I send it to other modules?

Comment: in the main file you make the declaration with args ```create_logger(args)``` and in the others files of the package or lib you juste call the method without args ```create_logger()``` because the @memoize schould store the logger in the cache.

Comment: I have tried, really, but I can’t understand your answer sorry. Singletons, cache methods... too complicated for my level. I wonder if this can be achieved using globals(). Eventually my problem is to make an instance of Logger global.